# Discord bot: The base SlashCommand cannot be instantiated

Tags: heroku, discord

On my computer it works fine, but when I try to host it on Heroku it gives this error

/app/node_modules/slash-create/lib/command.js:21
throw new Error('The base SlashCommand cannot be instantiated.');
^

Error: The base SlashCommand cannot be instantiated.
at new SlashCommand (/app/node_modules/slash-create/lib/command.js:21:19)
at new module.exports (/app/commands/back.js:5:9)
at SlashCreator.registerCommand (/app/node_modules/slash-create/lib/creator.js:64:23)
at SlashCreator.registerCommands (/app/node_modules/slash-create/lib/creator.js:105:18)
at SlashCreator.registerCommandsIn (/app/node_modules/slash-create/lib/creator.js:132:21)
at Object. (/app/index.js:39:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to register the base SlashCommand class as a command. You have to extend off of the class and add options to your command.

```js
const { SlashCommand, CommandOptionType } = require('slash-create');

module.exports = class HelloCommand extends SlashCommand {
  constructor(creator) {
    super(creator, {
      name: 'hello',
      description: 'Says hello to you.',
      options: [{
        type: CommandOptionType.STRING,
        name: 'food',
        description: 'What food do you like?'
      }]
    });

    this.filePath = __filename;
  }

  async run(ctx) {
    return ctx.options.food ? `You like ${ctx.options.food}? Nice!` : `Hello, ${ctx.user.username}!`;
  }
}
```

- [slash-create Example commands](https://slash-create.js.org/#/docs/main/latest/examples/command)
- [slash-create template (with Heroku button)](https://github.com/Snazzah/slash-create-template)